# What are the pros/cons/substitutes for using MySQL Connector/MXJ for an application

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, mysql-connector, embedded-database

I recently made an interesting application using Play Framework and MySQL Connector/MXJ to make a completely portable web server with database, independent of any currently installed software(including Java).

I'm still new to MXJ, and the desktop application realm (as opposed to straight-up webapps), so I'm wondering if there are other, better methods for storing/accessing large amounts of data than embedded MySQL.  I would assume so, since it seems not many people use MXJ.  It essentially just packs `mysqld.exe` in its various forms for multiple operating systems and platforms.  It runs in its own thread, and stores its data in whatever directory you provide.

For an application that frequently analyzes and searches through data in large chunks(100MB to 5GB), what other (fast)options are there, or am I justified in my webapp-laziness of bringing along MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Independent of any currently installed software(including Java).

If you are looking for an embedded database for a desktop application, then you can go for [SQLITE](http://www.sqlite.org/). However, there are pros/cons for using either MySQL or SQLite

**SQLite:**

1. Easier to setup
2. Great for temporary (testing databases)
3. Great for rapid development
4. Great for embedding in an application
5. Doesn't have user management
6. Doesn't have many performance features
7. Doesn't scale well.

MySQL:

1. Far more difficult/complex to set up
2. Better options for performance tuning
3. Fit for a production database
4. Can scale well if tuned properly
5. Can manage users, permissions, etc.

You can find more info on when to use SQLite [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

**UPDATE:** I came across [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) and [here](http://hsqldb.org/PolePosition.pdf) are its test results. [HamsterDb](http://hamsterdb.com/about) is another option.

Comment: Good analysis, I think.  Yes, I've used SQLite, and I like how easy it is to use, and how portable it is.  I think it wins in those cases, but whenever my data goes over a few MB, its performance degrades very rapidly.

Comment: Well, I came across [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) and [here](http://hsqldb.org/PolePosition.pdf) are its test results. [HamsterDb](http://hamsterdb.com/about) is another option.

Comment: Thanks, those are the kind of suggestions I was looking for.

Comment: I would say put those in your answer along with sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a database if your app is single user and desktop based? Maybe it is faster to simply write large files to the local filesystem then loading then through the network tier. If your app is very complex you could use an embedded db just for storing your domain and configuration, but if its not maybe you can avoid using a db + sql + o/r-mapping and so on.

Comment: Well, it's not single user.  This specific application is a web server to be put on any full OS, including tablets(not iPad or Android).  Basically a portable intranet for custom wi-fi devices.  Besides this specific application, though, I'm just trying to find the best general solution for accessing/sorting/analyzing/changing/comparing large amounts of data on a frequent basis.  I thought of just using a file system, but loading several 300 MB files into memory just for a quick comparison doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: Primarily ints and longs from high-sampling sensors, such as gyroscopes, gps, and accelerometers.

Comment: You are right, for analysis and comparisson that would be a mess. I guess a standalone database with well defined indexes in your large tables would be the best idea.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what do you mean by "loading them through the network tier"?

Comment: If you use a database dirver it will access your data over the network, or is there another way? Even if you use the loop-back adapter. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: No, you're right, I was just confused thinking of flat-file storage access through the network.